# ActiveRecord, how to select empty fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to count all User with empty last_name.

I'm trying those but they don't work

```
User.where("last_name = ?", "").count
User.where("last_name = ?", nil).count
```

Calling all against nil works but I still need to select those who's last_name are empty.

```
User.where("last_name != ?", nil).count
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User.where(:last_name => nil).count
```

Or using ARel:

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:last_name] == nil).count
```

Answer (score 1):

For mysql maybe:

```
User.where("last_name is null").count
```

otherwise maybe:

```
User.find_all_by_last_name(nil).count
```